# Understanding Integer Range

Tags: java

I'm teaching AP Comp Science and I can't figure out a simple way to explain how a student could answer this Java question.  It's one thing to understand the answer and another to explain to a student how to answer it in a limited amount of time.

```
    int sum = 0, p = 1;
    for (int count = 1; count <= 50; count++)
    {
         sum += p;
         p *= 2;  
    } 
    System.out.println(sum);
```

Oh yea, the answer is -1.

Comment: I think it is easier if they understand how integers are represented in memory ( signed 32 bits)

Answer (score 2):

The way I understood it, when I was reading your code, was that the two's complement binary representation of `-1` is all ones, and that's exactly what your code builds up: it does the equivalent of (simplified to a pretend four-bit type):

```
 0001
+0010
+0100
+1000
+0000 // overflow hits here
-----
 1111 // the binary representation of -1
```

...and the reason that the binary representation of -1 is all ones is that, continuing with our pretend four-bit integer type,

```
abcd = a * -2^3 + b * 2^2 + c * 2^1 + d * 2^0
```

...noting that the way two's complement works is that the first bit -- the top bit, `a` here -- has its sign swapped; it's multiplied by -2^3 instead of 2^3.  So 1111 is -8 + 4 + 2 + 1 = -8 + 7 = -1.

Answer (score 2):

If you change your code to the following:

```
int sum = 0, p = 1;
for (int count = 1; count <= 32; count++) {
    sum += p;
    p *= 2;
    System.out.printf("%-10s = %s%n", sum, Integer.toBinaryString(sum));
}
```

<sub>I have reduced the loop size to `32` as that is that that's required.</sub>

Then the output becomes:

```
1          = 1
3          = 11
7          = 111
15         = 1111
31         = 11111
63         = 111111
127        = 1111111
255        = 11111111
511        = 111111111
1023       = 1111111111
2047       = 11111111111
4095       = 111111111111
8191       = 1111111111111
16383      = 11111111111111
32767      = 111111111111111
65535      = 1111111111111111
131071     = 11111111111111111
262143     = 111111111111111111
524287     = 1111111111111111111
1048575    = 11111111111111111111
2097151    = 111111111111111111111
4194303    = 1111111111111111111111
8388607    = 11111111111111111111111
16777215   = 111111111111111111111111
33554431   = 1111111111111111111111111
67108863   = 11111111111111111111111111
134217727  = 111111111111111111111111111
268435455  = 1111111111111111111111111111
536870911  = 11111111111111111111111111111
1073741823 = 111111111111111111111111111111
2147483647 = 1111111111111111111111111111111
-1         = 11111111111111111111111111111111
```

This becomes clearer. You are multiplying `p` by `2` each time, and adding it to `sum`.

This is similar to a bitshift operation, i.e. you are adding one `1` to the binary representation each time.

An `int` has 32 bits of space - eventually it runs out of space, and "overflows". In Java an `int` is a two's complement representation, so when the size overflows the sign bit, the `int` become negative.

Comment: very nice triangle :)